# How can i determine if service accounts are in use using the cli?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I want to determine which service accounts in the console are being used and those that aren't.
Using `gcloud iam service-accounts list`, I'm able to get the list of accounts.
Using `gcloud iam service-accounts keys list --iam-account=<IAM_ACCOUNT>` shows me when the keys were created and when they expire.
However i'm not able to determine if they accounts were ever used. 
What can i do to find this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is not directly possible, as in a method like `gcloud iam service-accounts describe` will not give this information, and neither the IAM API or Cloud Console will give you this information.

Your best shot at this would be reading the activity logs of your project with [`gcloud logging read`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/read) and filter those logs, looking for the service account that you want to use.

If you see that it could be useful to have such a feature in a better way, as in having this information in the `describe` command, feel free to open a request in [the Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187161&template=1010429)

Answer (score 0):

There might now be a better solution to this:

1. Export the Cloud Asset Inventory data to BigQuery: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/exporting-to-bigquery
2. Analyze the exported table for usage of the mentioned service account.

Example Cloud Workflow to regularly export the asset metadata to BigQuery:

```yaml
main:
    params: []
    steps:
    - init:
        assign:
            - organization: organizations/YOUR_ORG_ID
            - dataset: projects/DEST_PROJECT_ID/datasets/cloud_assets
    - triggerExportToBigQuery:
        for:
            value: contentType
            in: ["ACCESS_POLICY", "IAM_POLICY", "ORG_POLICY", "OS_INVENTORY", "RESOURCE"] # RELATIONSHIP is only support SCC Premium customers
            steps:
                - callApi:
                    call: http.post
                    args:
                        url: ${"https://cloudasset.googleapis.com/v1/" + organization + ":exportAssets"}
                        auth:
                            type: OAuth2
                        headers:
                            x-goog-user-project: CALLING_PROJECT_ID
                        body:
                            contentType: ${contentType}
                            outputConfig:
                                bigqueryDestination:
                                    dataset: ${dataset}
                                    table: ${text.to_lower(contentType)}
                                    force: true
```

Example SQL query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `projectID.cloud_assets.resource`
WHERE resource.data LIKE '%service-account-name@projectID.iam.gserviceaccount.com%'
```